# Javascript - How to wait for a async function to finish to execute another function then?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, callback, wait

I'm working on two functions about my project. First function is async function:

```
async function abc(params) {
(...)
var sdata = JSON.stringify(params);
fetch(...)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        /*do something*/
    })
    .catch(err => {
        /*err do something*/
    })
}
```

Second function is:

```
function xyz (param){
    irrevelantFunction(param);
}
```

I tried to execute this two functions like below:

```
abc(params).then(xyz(param));
```

but it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem? Many thanks for your precious support.

Comment: You forgot to `return` the Promise. You also don't want to invoke `xyz` immediately, instead just *pass* the `xyz` function to `.then`

Comment: If you are using .then then you don't need to use async await, either one you can use

Comment: @CertainPerformance I added `return` to promise. But I didn't understand how can I run these functions in a specific order.

Comment: Like I said, just pass `xyz`: `abc(params).then(xyz);`

Comment: But I have to give a parameter to xyz.If I pass xyz without parameter, it give null value error

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks for your support. 
I create a new empty function and I passed xyz into this new function. 
Then I invoke the new function at abc's `.then` and it solved.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using async then you can avoid **.then**, kindly see the sample snippet code

```js
async function abc(params) {
var sdata = JSON.stringify(params);
try{
  const response = await fetch(...)
  if(response.ok){
    const body = await response.json();
    xyz(body)
    return
  }
  const cusotomError = {
   message: 'something went wrong'
  }
  throw customError
}catch(error){
  console.log(error) // you can show error to ui logic
}



function xyz (param){
    irrevelantFunction(param);
}
```

Comment: I'll call these functions in another function and xyz's parameter is different from abc's.

Comment: The above snippet is a demo one how to achieve you can use customise as you required

Comment: Kindly please tell on the comments for downvoting :(